# Concatenate values from columns without grouping rows SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average, percentile

This is the table I have:

```
clientId | value | date |
1        |      2| Jan 1|
1        |      3| Jan 2|
1        |      4| Jan 5|
2        |      1| Jan 1|
2        |      2| Jan 2|
2        |      7| Jan 6|
```

I want to delete rows where the value is below the 25th Percentile of all values for each client, and above the 75th Percentile. Then I want to average the values that are remaining. My Idea has been to concatenate the value rows together in ascending order and then uSE SUBSTRING_INDEX to remove the values above or below the threshholds, calculated by using COUNT(*) :

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(`transactionCount` ORDER BY
`transactionCount` SEPARATOR ','), ',', -(75 / 100 * COUNT(*))),
',', ROUND(75 / 100 * COUNT(*) -1)) AS sub2
```

At this point I get the concatenated string back without the values I dont want. My next step would be to average the values that remain, but I can't do that at this point because the values are all in a string now.

1. Is there a way to average out the values in the string in the same sql query?
2. Is this a totally unnecessary way to get rid of values below the 25th and above the 75th percentile of all values? Is there a way to do it better? I imagine there must be a way to set a HAVING clause that can calcuate the percentiles and remove values below or above them, right? Something like: HAVING value >= 25thPercentileOfValues AND value <= 75thPercentileOfValues. 
   But how would I measure those two values :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you guys :D

Comment: Your code looks like MySQL, so I added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is [`ntile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), filter, and then aggregate:

```
select clientid, avg(value)
from (select t.*, ntile(4) over (partition by clientid order by value) as tile
      from t
     ) t
where tile in (2, 3)
group by clientid;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :D I keep getting an SQL error: 

[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY value) as tile' 

any idea why?

Comment: @fais . . . `ntile()` is available since the release of MySQL 8.0.